# is it bad practice to call dictConfig more than once?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, logging

I am using `logging.config.dictConfig()` to setup logging into files using `FileHandler` and `RotatingFileHandler`. is it bad practice to call `dictConfig()` more than once? if so why?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the question is more broad than just going down to calling a method twice.

1) Is it a bad practice to call `dictConfig` more than once? - No, it is not. You can use it happily as long as you understand what happens.

2) Can it be considered a bad practice or lead to unexpected results in some context? - Yes, for sure.

If you check the source code of [`dictConfig`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/logging/config.py#L792) you will not find anything that could possibly harm running code. All configuration is wrapped in a lock so calling method is safe.

However, what you should be aware is what happens to existing loggers in `_handle_existing_loggers`.
By default all existing loggers are going to be **disabled** and this is important, read it again, **disabled**, not **removed**. They still exist but do not any work anymore and, for instance, in they might prevent message propagation to parent loggers. (more reading [here](https://www.caktusgroup.com/blog/2015/01/27/Django-Logging-Configuration-logging_config-default-settings-logger/), actual code: [python source](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.4/Lib/logging/__init__.py#l1418))

You can test what happens with loggers using this [Gist](https://gist.github.com/alanbriolat/d5ffe608b56c948533c6) (while I do not agree with a gist description).

Overall, my advice would be - try to configure all the loggers at once. There are cases when you need to add loggers on the fly, which is not bad, just make sure you know what happens or just pass `False` as `disable_existing_loggers` parameter if you want to extend loggers config.

Cheers and safe coding!